# Clear SSL State using vbscript

Tags: ssl, vbscript, browser-automation, clear-cache

As a part of my project I have to automate a web application running over secure socket layer. So I have to clear SSL state, Cache, Browsing history using vbscript, after logout, if some account didn't work properly. I have written following code so far but it is not working properly.

```
ieObj.document.execCommand ("ClearAuthenticationCache")

 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
 Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(TEMPORARY_INTERNET_FILES)
 objFSO.DeleteFile (objFolder.Self.Path & "\*.*")
 ieObj.Quit
 Set ieObj = Nothing
 Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
```

Just to update right now I am clearing the ssl state using sendkeys,

```
Sub ClearSSLState()
' Macro1 Macro
Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
oShell.Run ("cmd")
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
oShell.AppActivate "C:\SYSROOT\system32\cmd.exe"

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
oShell.SendKeys "inetcpl.cpl"
oShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
oShell.AppActivate "Internet Properties"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
oShell.SendKeys "^{TAB 3}"
oShell.SendKeys "{Tab}"

oShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
oShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
oShell.SendKeys "{Tab 6}"
oShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

oShell.AppActivate "C:\SYSROOT\system32\cmd.exe"
oShell.SendKeys "exit"
oShell.SendKeys "{enter}"

End Sub
```

Would really appreciate, if someone please suggest any option to clear ssl state as well using vbscript.

Many Thanks :)

Comment: SSL means Secure Socket Layer, NOT Secure Shell, so you'll need to reconsider your script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When instrumenting the Control Panel action with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) (a great utility, BTW), it looks like the following command is executed when the *Clear SSL State* button is pressed:

```
"C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" "C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll",DispatchAPICall 3
```